# Implicit conversion of int to NSString is disallowed with ARC and Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to NSString from int

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm having a bit of trouble with some code a developer gave to on this website. The code is meant to check for an internet connection. This is the code below:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, getter = isConnected) NSString *connected;



[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"];

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // hide the activity indicator

    self.connected = (s != nil);



    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

    if (self.isConnected)
    {
        NSLog(@"self.connected == YES");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"self.connected == NO");
        NSString *alertMessage = @"In order to load images, you need an active Internet connection. Please try again later!";

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:alertMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }
});
```

This code is placed in the `viewDidLoad` but I keep getting 2 errors saying `Implicit conversion of int to NSString is disallowed with ARC` and `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSString *' from 'int'` for `self.connected = (s != nil);`.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property `connected` is of type `NSString *`. You can't assign a bool to it (`self.connected = (s != nil);`).

I think what you intended to do is declare your property as `BOOL`:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isConnected) BOOL connected;
```

Under the hood, `BOOL` is just an `int`, so when assigning an int to an `NSString *` typed variable, the compiler understand that you want to change the value of your pointer directly, which is disallowed in ARC (and is a bad idea anyway); hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
self.connected = (s != nil);
```

`(s != nil)` will return 0 or 1 not an NSString object